# Different Output of Pyspark code on same set of data while multiple runs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have write one pyspark function,but when i run multiple times its giving me every time diffrent outputs 
on same set of input data.

-pyspark Function

```
def give_percentile(plat,metrics,perc):
df_perc = df_final.filter(df_final.platform.like('%' + plat + '%'))
df_perc = df_perc.filter(df_final[metrics]!=0)
percentile_val = df_perc.approxQuantile(metrics, [perc], 0.05)
if len(percentile_val)>0:
    percentile_val = float(percentile_val[0])
else:
    percentile_val = float(0)
return percentile_val
```

Calling Function-

```
   df_agg = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(platform='iOS',
                                        percentile_page_load_50=give_percentile("iOS","page_load",0.5),
                                        percentile_time_diff_50=give_percentile("iOS","session_duration",0.5)),
                                        Row(platform='Android',
                                        percentile_page_load_50=give_percentile("Android","page_load",0.5),
                                        percentile_time_diff_50=give_percentile("Android","session_duration",0.5)),
                                        Row(platform='Web',
                                        percentile_page_load_50=give_percentile("Web","page_load",0.5),
                                        percentile_time_diff_50=give_percentile("Web","session_duration",0.5)))
```

Spark Job Submit:-

```
    spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster  --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 12G --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 12G --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC "path"
```

we are storing the output of pyspark code in parquet file format and on top of it we are creating impala table as below:

1.select a.percentile_page_load_50,a.percentile_time_diff_50 from Tablename1 a where a.platform ='Colvalue' and 
a.dt ='20190501' limit 5;
Table Record Count= 22093826

Output =0.62400001287460327
        0.35100001096725464

2.select a.percentile_page_load_50,a.percentile_time_diff_50 from Tablename2 a where a.platform ='Colvalue' and 
a.dt ='20190501' limit 5;
Table Record Count= 22093826

output=0.61500000953674316
       0.28499999642372131
3.select a.percentile_page_load_50,a.percentile_time_diff_50 from Tablename3 a where a.platform ='Colvalue' and 
a.dt ='20190501' limit 5;
Table Record Count= 22093826

output= 0.61799997091293335
        0.27799999713897705

now here Tablename1,Tablename2 and Tablename3 are created the output of multiple run of pyspark code on same set of input data.
but still the values are diffrent as our pyspark code is running in cluser mode/distributed mode. When we checked for sample data on 
standlone mode its values are not changing.
So could you please help me here and tell me what is wrong in the above function code or any other cluster issue?

Comment: You set the allowed error of the approxQuantile function to 0.05, which means it is only deterministic with the following bounds: "If the DataFrame has N elements and if we request the quantile at probability p up to error err, then the algorithm will return a sample x from the DataFrame so that the exact rank of x is close to (p * N)." [Link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile)

Comment: @cronoik you should write that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The function approxQuantile gives you an approximate solution depending on the given relativeError. You set the allowed relativeError of the approxQuantile function to 0.05, which means it is only deterministic with the following bounds:

"If the DataFrame has N elements and if we request the quantile at probability p up to error err, then the algorithm will return a **sample x** from the DataFrame so that the exact rank of x is close to (p * N)." (I have highlighted the part why you get different results).

You have to set the relativeError to 0.0 in case you need the exact quantiles, but this also increases the runtime. 
More information can be found in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile).